# How do I make a global variable using local variables?

Tags: javascript

I am making a new video game and I need help with a purchase feature.
I want to use local variables to "create" a global variable. For example:

```
function example(apple,banana) {
    return unicorn.apple.banana.text
}
example(taco,burrito);
```

should return whatever `unicorn.taco.burrito.text` equals.

Comment: There are probably 100 duplicate questions here on this same topic.

Answer (score 4):

For this you need to use the Array Notation.

```
function example(apple, banana) {
    return unicorn[apple][banana].text
}
example(taco, burrito);
```

Because you need to replace `apple` and `banana`, with their values.

Comment: Did not work out so how about I show you the **real** code.

`frac.percent.buy = function (shop,purchase) {
  if (frac.buckaroonies >= frac[shop].shopcost[purchase].cost) {
    frac[shop].num = frac[shop].shopcost[purchase].addition + frac[shop].num;
    frac.buckaroonies = frac.buckaroonies - frac[shop].shopcost[purchase].cost;
  }
};`

Comment: I try `frac.percent.buy(percent,one);` and I'm left with: 
`one is not defined

Comment: @EXmaster Show your full code.